# How do I save a contact in zimbra using its javascript API?

Tags: zimbra

I managed to add a button in the contacts toolbar in Zimbra's UI using Zimbra's Javascript API. Is there a way to save the contact that is currently beeing edited using the javascript API again ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround which is just grab the save button and emulate a click on it.

```
SugarBee.prototype.saveContactAndSendToSugar = function (toolbar,controller,ev) {
    [...code...]
    var save_button = toolbar.getButton("SAVE");
    save_button._emulateSingleClick();
    [...code...]

}
```